# Move mouse while Cursor is hidden ingame

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently creating a very small application, that prevents me from being afk kicked on minecraft servers. The way this works is, every x seconds it moves my mouse back and forth.
Even though it technically works fine, it wont move my mouse when im in Minecraft. It will only move my mouse, if the cursor is actually visible. While being ingame, the cursor is hidden, so it wont work.
To actually move the mouse im using:

```
Point location = new Point(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X+moveAmount, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y);
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = location;
```

Has anyone got an idea, why it wont work in Minecraft and how i can fix it?

I found this question here on stackoverflow, but even that did not work:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;

    public static void Move(int xDelta, int yDelta)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, xDelta, yDelta, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't play the game but how do you move the character?  Perhaps you could utilize the left and right direction arrow clicks to move it?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Sadly thats not solving it for me. Just moving left and right wont prevent me from being kicked. I have to move the mouse. (Moving the head ingame)

Comment: perhaps this might give you some direction: https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/994u6t/simulate_mouse_scroll_up_and_down_in_c/

Comment: Games use raw input to stop users from cheating.  So they only see input that actually came from the device driver, hacking Cursor.Position or mouse_event() or SendInput does nothing.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: But is there a solution to actually get this working in games like Minecraft?

Comment: The easiest solution here is to use AutoHotKey and not c#.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i actually managed to do it.
After some research and trying many different things, this is what worked:

```
[Flags]
    public enum MouseEventFlags {
        LeftDown = 0x00000002,
        LeftUp = 0x00000004,
        MiddleDown = 0x00000020,
        MiddleUp = 0x00000040,
        Move = 0x00000001,
        Absolute = 0x00008000,
        RightDown = 0x00000008,
        RightUp = 0x00000010
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    public static void MouseEvent(MouseEventFlags value, MousePoint position2) {
        MousePoint position = position2;

        mouse_event
            ((int)value,
             position.X,
             position.Y,
             0,
             0)
            ;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MousePoint {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public MousePoint(int x, int y) {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

    }
```

How to call the Method:

```
MouseEvent(MouseEventFlags.Move, new MousePoint { X = 100, Y = 100 });
```